# How you distribute python 3.X GUI application to end user?

Tags: python-3.x, distribution

Seems the Python3.X don't have a solution to convert the python application to executable on Mac OS X. So, I think it requires a work around for end user. How you package your software / script to end user? Any advices? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The better solution so far is cx_Freeze. It converts the script to a executable program which calls the python compiled modules packaged into a zip file. It works pretty simple and you can use other tools to create a self extract .exe file. The WinRar itself has such tool, as well as many others.
Take a look at the cx_Freeze docs here:
http://cx-freeze.sourceforge.net/cx_Freeze.html